# Excel rounding numbers on comparison formulas

Tags: excel, decimal, formula

I have some delicate formula comparing numbers that are between 1 and 0, but Excel insists in round them up inside the formula, which was detected whilst evaluating it.

I have

```
 =IF(C65=(LARGE(BA$65:BA$88;1));1;0)
```

where C65 = 0.91
and the largest number in the BA65:BA88 range is 1.
it detects incorrectly that C65 and 1 are equal and outputs the wrong result.
On evaluating i saw that it was rouding up 0.91 to 1.

i've tried using ROUND(C65,2) but no success

how can I force the formula to have a decimal vaule on the comparison step?

EDIT:

the 0.91 comes from a Cell with another formula

```
 =IFERROR(IF(LARGE(C$65:C$88;$AA73)=LARGE(C$65:C$88;$AA72);LARGE(C$65:C$88;$AA73)-$AA73*0,01;LARGE(C$65:C$88;$AA73));0)
```

basically it is being used to get itens ranked from a list (index() and rank() werent helpful at all at achieving what i want so i decided to pick the numbers and make a decimal subtraction so i can find precise rank location with MATCH() only )

the results from BA65 to BA88 at the rows are

- 4,00 (from 4)
- 3,00 (from 3)
- 2,00 (from 2)
- 1,96 (from repeated 2)
- 1,00 (from 1)
- 0,94 (from repeated 1)
- 0,93 (from second repeated 1)
- 0,92 (for third repeated 1)
- 0,91 (forth)
- 0,90 (fifth)
- 0,89 (sixth)

0 is fallback value / not ranked

Comment: are you sure your formula is correct,  if seems to me that it should be `=IF(C65=(LARGE(BA$65:BA$88;1);1;0)`

Comment: my bad. i just pasted it wrong. i'll fix it

Comment: Did you check the steps with "evaluate formula" under the formulas tab?

Comment: If your values are because of another formula you may find that you need to compare to a range of numbers instead of a static one.  When working with decimals many times there are differences in .910001 and .91, that is enough for excel to say they are not equal. So you would want something like this `=IF(AND(LARGE(BA$65:BA$88;1)>= C65-.001;LARGE(BA$65:BA$88;1)<= C65+.001);1;0)`

Comment: @ScottCraner almost there, it correctly recognizes one of the numbers as decimal, but other still not, causing the same issue, it is already imported wrong, so im just removing 0.001 from an already wrongly imported number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason, after i changed the C65 formula to

```
 =NOT(IFERROR(LARGE(C$65:C$88;$AA65)); 
    IF(LARGE(C$65:C$88;$AA65)=LARGE(C$65:C$88;$AA64);
    LARGE(C$65:C$88;$AA65)-$AA65*0,01;
    LARGE(C$65:C$88;$AA65))
  )
```

it got it right.
may be it was an issue with the IFERROR() output